# get the UDP videostreaming in gstreamer with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer

I would like to receive a video stream from gstreamer using Opencv/python.
The camera is connected to FPGA board which connect to PC through Ethernet.
i could get the streaming data from terminal command but failed in python script.

Talking of the gstreamer pipeline in FPGA,the script goes like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080,format=UYVY ! rtpvrawpay mtu=$MTU ! udpsink host=$HOST_IP port="5005" & fi
```

then i want to get the stream data from my PC, firstly, i used command goes

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, sampling=YCbCr-4:2:2, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1920, height=(string )1080" port="5005" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=xvimagesink text-overlay=true sync=false
```

And i succeed get the camera data realtime, and then when i use python, the code goes

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())

gstreamer_str = 'udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, sampling=YCbCr-4:2:2, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1920, height=(string )1080" port =5004 ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=xvimagesink text-overlay=true sync=false ! appsink'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
#cap =cv2.VideoCapture('autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Input via Gstreamer", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        else:
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the

```
cv2.getBuildInformation
```

is fine,the result of GStreamer is YES (1.20.3)

And when i run the python script, i can not get the streaming data, the condition goes:
[the running condition of python data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exFmR.png)

And i got the error message

```
(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:13:01.636: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:13:01.636: gst_structure_get_int: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
[ WARN:0@30.020] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1714 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot query video width/height

(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:13:01.636: gst_structure_get_fraction: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
[ WARN:0@30.020] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1722 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot query video fps
[ WARN:0@30.021] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1777 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1

(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:14:06.637: gst_sample_get_caps: assertion 'GST_IS_SAMPLE (sample)' failed
[ERROR:0@95.021] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:934 retrieveVideoFrame GStreamer: gst_sample_get_caps() returns NULL
None
None

(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:15:11.637: gst_sample_get_caps: assertion 'GST_IS_SAMPLE (sample)' failed
[ERROR:0@160.022] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:934 retrieveVideoFrame GStreamer: gst_sample_get_caps() returns NULL

(python3:67417): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:16:16.638: gst_sample_get_caps: assertion 'GST_IS_SAMPLE (sample)' failed
[ERROR:0@225.022] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:934 retrieveVideoFrame GStreamer: gst_sample_get_caps() returns NULL
None
```

could you please how to fix it? Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: `if ret:`,  then you're getting blank window.

Comment: I can get the first frame of the video, and then the python code become freeze